# Bool function always returning false

Tags: c++, function, boolean

Hi my trying to create a function that lets the user know if the word entered is a palindrome (is the same spelled backwards, ex: kayak). This is the function I came up with, yet for some reason the function always return false.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

bool compare(string str2)
{
    int first = 0, mid, last = (str2.size() - 1);

    while(first < last)
    {
        if(first == last)
        {
            first++;
            last--;
        }
        else return(false);
    }
    return(true);  
}

int main()
{
    string pal;

    cout <<"Enter your single word palindrome: ";
    getline(cin,pal);

    if(compare(pal) == true)cout << pal <<" is a palindrome.\n";
    else                    cout << pal <<" is not a palindrome.\n";

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: if(first == last) --> first and last are the index digits, you need to compare the chars

Comment: Where you have your while loop, your if is wrong. you need `str2[first] == str2[last]` beause you're checking that both `first` is less than `last`, and that `first` is the same as `last`, which cannot both be true.

Comment: Do you mean `str2[first] == str2[last]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually doing any character comparison, just comparing the indexes `first` and `last` - they don't match so you return false.

Answer (score 1):

Following the code below, if we assume `last` is greater than 0, `while(first < last)` is `true` followed by `if(first == last)` being `false` and therefore the function returns `false`.  I'm guessing you might want to be comparing the characters instead of the indices.

```
int first = 0, mid, last = (str2.size() - 1);

while(first < last)
{
    if(first == last)
    {
        first++;
        last--;
    }
    else return(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if (first == last) { } 
This is the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should compare `char` not `int`. So try this:

```
bool compare(string str2)
{
    int first = 0, mid, last = (str2.size() - 1);

    while(first] < last)
    {
        if(str2[first] == str2[last])
        {
            first++;
            last--;
        }
        else 
            return(false);
    }
    return(true);  
}
```